# How to install Gnome 3.x in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

So Ubuntu 21.10 comes with Gnome 40 but I am wondering how I might install the older Gnome 3.36 instead? What are the steps necessary to do this?

Comment: Even if possible - doubtfully - it certainly isn't recommended.

Comment: This may be another [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to use GNOME 3.36 in 21.10?

Comment: Do fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and use it for another 4 years of support.

Answer (score 0):

Linux distributions allow users with little technical skills to set up and use a linux operating system. Users with great technical skills can set up their own linux operating system.

Thus, you could install Gnome Shell 3.36 from source code. Doing so probably will require you to replace a lot of components of 21.10 to older components as required by this older Gnome Shell version. You will need to overhaul your 21.10 system very deeply. You understand that this will become very complicated. After this, you will need to disable your software sources: many software packaged for 21.10 will not anymore work on your deeply customized install of 21.10, because the dependencies do not anymore match. That could then be solved by installing each and every program by compiling source code - sorting out dependencies every time.

Except if you have keen interest and a lot of time to spare, do yourself a favor: install Ubuntu 20.04 and use a preconfigured operating system using Gnome 3.36 for another four supported years.